# Checksum error while updating module

Tags: 7, drush, updating

I ran pm-update with drush which is giving me this error

> File mediabox-7.x-1.x-dev.tar.gz_date=1393593819 is corrupt (wrong
>   [error] md5 checksum). Updating project mediabox failed. Attempting to
>   roll back to         [error] previously installed version. Backups
>   were restored successfully.                                  [ok]

Same thing worked on my local server but not on ubuntu server. Anyone know how to resolve this issue? I can manually copy the files but I am not looking for that solution.